# Checkbox function for checking if input is "checked" or not "checked"

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox, click

I want some elements to have a class applied to them if a checkbox is checked, and to have the class removed if they are *not* checked (or un-checked). I've tried writing this a few different ways but I'm only ever able to give apply the class to the elements once the checkbox is clicked, but re-clicking doesn't remove the class from the elements even though I expect it would.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {

    if($('#filter-Acting').prop('checked') == true) {

      $('.filter-item.Acting').addClass("hidden");

    } else if ($('#filter-Acting').prop('checked') == false) {

      $('.filter-item.Acting').removeClass("hidden");

    } 

  }
});
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish what I'm after? Thanks.

*EDIT: None of the provided examples have worked for me so here is relevant markup for the form and a form item...

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="checkbox" id="check-Acting">
          <input type="checkbox" id="filter-Acting" name="Acting" value="1" class="form-checkbox"/>
          <label for="filter-Acting" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><span>Acting</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel filter-item Acting">
    --
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you try the `"change"` event instead of the click? Also, what does your HTML markup look like? You may just want to have the click/change event firing on `#fliter-item.Acting` instead of the `input`

Comment: You can use the `'change'` event. Take a look here https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Tried replacing 'click' with 'change' but the results are the same... I'll post some of my markup shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your html I may only assume it and propose you to use:

[.toggleClass( className, state )](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state): one or more class to be toggled according to the state value

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function (e) {
    $('.filter-Acting').toggleClass("hidden", !$('#filter-item.Acting').is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="....">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="filter-item" class="Acting"> Click me<br>
    <input type="text" class="filter-Acting hidden"><br>
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I reviewed my code and corrected some of my own markup errors and now this seems to work the way I need it to. Thanks very much for your response.

Comment: @MylesMalloy I'm glad to help you. Thanks